# How to call C++ library code from Xamarin Forms project - DllNotFoundException

Tags: c#, c++, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have Xamarin forms cross platform project - Android, iOS and UWP. I have a C++ DLL project from which I have created a DLL. My intention is to integrate/call these C++ code within Xamarin forms cross. I know how to call C++ from C# Console application with `DLLImport` assembly directive, but on Xamarin I get `DllNotFoundException`.

So where the DLL file has to be copied or referenced for this to work?

- I have copied `.dll` and other files in Debug folder(where the current project is trying to reference DLL. (*I referred this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V5hZRtSB-2Q) and it works for C# console* )
- Even tried Add Reference to DLL file - gives error cannot add file
- Adding C++ DLL project to same solution and referencing it is giving `System.DllNotFoundException`.
- Created cross platform shared C++ (I think this is comes in NDK)library project but still get the same issue - `DllNotFoundException`.

### Code :

1. C++

   ```
   #include "stdafx.h"

   extern "C"{

       __declspec(dllexport) int add(int a, int b)
       {
           return a + b;
       }
       __declspec(dllexport) int subtract(int a, int b)
       {
           return a - b;
       }
   }
   ```
2. App.xaml.cs or any other .Net standard shared project

   ```
   public partial class App : Application
   {
   [DllImport("Dll1.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
   public static extern int subtract(int a, int b);


   [DllImport("Dll1.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
   public static extern int add(int a, int b);

   [DllImport("XamCppDll.Shared.so")]
   public static extern int cpp_GetValue(int a, int b);

   public App()
   {
       InitializeComponent();

       int x = 100;
       int y = 15;
       int z = 0;
       int z1 = 0;
       try
       {
           cpp_GetValue(5, 6);//XamCppDll.Shared.so
           z = subtract(x, y);//Dll1.dll
           z1 = add(x, y);//Dll1.dll
       }
       catch (System.Exception ex1)
       {
           Debug.WriteLine(ex1.Message);
       }

       Debug.WriteLine(" {0} - {1} = {2}", x, y, z);
       Debug.WriteLine(" {0} + {1} = {2}", x, y, z1);

       MainPage = new MainPage();

   }
   ```

   }

#### Project structure

[image: project structure]

#### Tutorials/codes referred

https://blog.xamarin.com/build-and-debug-c-libraries-in-xamarin-android-apps-with-visual-studio-2015/

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/02/23/developing-xamarin-android-native-applications/

Comment: Isn't the problem XamCppDll.Shared.so souldn't it be  XamCppDll.Shared.dll ?

Comment: According to tutorial it would be .so I tried both .dll and .so ; they won't work. Neither Dll1.dll nor XamCppDll.Shared.so are found. It just gives not found exception with HResult - hex address , not mentioning .lib file for either approach.

Comment: Isn't the DllNotFoundException more precise, which library is not found? In my memory it was more precise...

Comment: @NPE getting precise error , I changed lib name on code and also tried do to sniffing by placing .so files but still same error.`D/Mono    (20164): DllImport attempting to load: 'libXamCppDll.so'. W/Mono    (20164): DllImport unable to load library 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/com.companyname.C__Test-1/lib/arm64/libXamCppDll.so" not found'.`

Comment: Are you sure all projets are compiled with the same target architecture (x86 or x64). Avoid any Any CPU lying aroud.

Comment: Yes,I tried avoiding that and did x86 for both android and C++ dll project. Somehow its not adding compiled dll(.so file) to apk file while debug. After some changes I got stopped due to [https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/hello-jni-Android-790ab73d/view/Discussions](Stopped due to shared library event (no libraries added or removed)

Comment: Also sample provided by [microsoft-xamarin is pretty old](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/xamarin-docs/issues/747)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured this issue after spending so much time and testing.

In order load library the C++ should be packed as `.so`(Shared Object) extension within Android.

This file has to be packed and placed within `.apk` of the android.

- Create and compile Xamarin C++ cross platform shared library project.
- Compile Android specific linked project to get different architecture
  .so : x86 , x64 , ARM, ARM64 - these correspond to different ABIs
  too.
- Link .so with android ABI

  1. **Option 1** : create `lib/abi_name` folder and set .so file as `AnroidNativeLibrary` where `abi_name` can be

     - armeabi
     - armeabi-v7a
     - arm64-v8a
     - x86
     - x86_64
           **Important note :** In order to .so file to being copied to APK folder structure should be exactly as above. If device supported architecture is arm64-v8a but only x86 folder is created then .so file wont be available within APK and we still get DllNotFoundException.
  2. **Option 2**: Add .so file into android project with Build action `AndroidNativeLibrary` with `<ABI>` tag specifier. In Android .csproj file add as below.

     ```
     <ItemGroup>
     <AndroidNativeLibrary Include="path/to/libFile.so">
         <Abi>armeabi</Abi>
     </AndroidNativeLibrary>
     ```

I have added Github repository [XamarinNDKSample](https://github.com/pmahend1/Xamarin/tree/master/XamarinNDKSample) for this if anyone wants working code.

Comment: HI, I am considering using an existing C++ library in Xamarin Forms project for IOS, Android, and UWP head projecets and I saw your post, thanks for sharing.  However, it looks to me that you are only providing solution for Android head project when you say "for Android, I have to convert dll to so".  Isn't that case for iOS and UWP as well?  Thanks

Comment: @pixel When you create cross platform C++ project you will get `.a` file which you can use for iOS and for UWP you can use your existing dll.

Comment: I have not created any C++ project.  I am basically trying to reuse an old C++ library in our Xamarin.Forms

Comment: what i understand is you can use that C++ lib (DLL?) in UWP and WPF Xamarin , android and iOS still need their specific files which can be embedded within installation package

Comment: Anyone has any idea about using C library in Xamarin.Forms UWP projects?

Comment: @Morse did you find anything about how to impliment this on Xamarin.iOS?

Comment: @RyanMotal Its been long I have worked on this , for IOS it should be similar approach , only difference is it will be `.a` file instead of `.so`